# c++: value initialization and default member initializer

Tags: c++, value-initialization

```cpp
struct MyType {
  const char *pointer{""};
};

struct MyTypeHolder {
 MyType my_type;

 MyType &GetMyType() { return my_type; }
};

int main () {
 MyTypeHolder my_type_holder;

 auto &my_type = my_type_holder.GetMyType();

 my_type = MyType{};

 // May one assert that my_type.pointer points to the empty string?
}
```

In the example above `my_type = MyType{}` a temporarily object of type `MyType` is value initialized. Because `MyType` has a default member initializer for a non-static member, can one assert that the `pointer` points to an empty string once the object is value initialized?

Comment: Why make the code more confusing than necessary? `MyType a; a = MyType{};` or `MyTypeHolder a; a.my_type = MyType{};` would remove unnecessary complexity. This question doesn't seem to be concerned with any effects of the variable being a member of an object or the reference to that member being initialized given the results of the member function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume C++14 or later for the answer. It was a bit different before that in terms of the formal rules, but with the same practical result.

---

> In the example above my_type = MyType{} a temporarily object of type MyType is value initialized.

No, the temporary is *aggregate-initialized*, because you use curly braces and `MyType` is an aggregate type (as it doesn't have any user-declared constructors and satisfies all other requirements of an aggregate class).

This means that no constructor is called (in contrast with value-initialization with parentheses which will call the implicitly-defined default constructor). Instead the `pointer` member of the temporary object is directly initialized with its default member initializer in the context of `main`, because there is no explicit initializer for it given in the braced initializer list from which the object is aggregate-initialized.

The effect is however the same: `pointer` of the temporary will point to an string literal object holding an empty string and after assigning to `my_type` with the implicitly-defined move constructor, `my_type.pointer` will also point to the same string literal object.

However, be aware that there is *no guarantee* that evaluating the string literal multiple times will yield a pointer to *the same* string literal object. This is completely up to the compiler.

So, yes you can `assert(my_type.pointer[0] == '\0');`, but not `assert(my_type.pointer == "");` or that two `pointer` obtained in this way hold the same address.